# Vue, get value and name of select option

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using html and laravel to build select box options in a foreach loop

This works and populates with ID as value and name as the option. What I want, and can't quite figure out here, is how to take my function when I call it and get the id and value as separate vue options for a post axios call I'm going to make.

So when I select the option and submit the form to call the function, how can I get the ID as one prop and the name as another?

```
<select>
@foreach($details as $detail)    
<option value="{{$detail->id}}">{{$detail->name}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>

new Vue({
  data: {
    detailID: [''],
    detailName: ['']
  },
  methods: {
   let data = {

                detailID: this.detailID,
                detailName: this.detailName
            };
  }
})
```

Comment: Not clear what you want and how you use it. Give us more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `v-model` to bind the selection to your component data. See[`Form input bindings`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html):

```js
new Vue({
   data: {
      detailID: ""
   },
   // now you can access the id with this.detailID in your post request
})
```

```html
<select v-model="detailID">
  @foreach($details as $detail)    
  <option value="{{$detail->id}}">{{$detail->name}}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

And if you need both `id` and `name`, one work around could be:

```js
new Vue({
   data: {
      detail: ""
   },
   // now you can access the id & name with this.detail.split(',') in your post request
})
```

```html
<select v-model="detail">
  @foreach($details as $detail)    
  <option value="{{$detail->id.','.$detail->name}}">{{$detail->name}}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Ok that does make sense, but I want to send the value for $detail->name as well. How can I grab both as individual bindings for my post?

Comment: Generally I would think you don't need `$detail->name` if `$detail->id` uniquely define a detail item? With that said, you should be able to filter your `$details` array by `id` to find the `name`?

Comment: ok so that works for the value, but I'm still confused using the split: How can I set the first option (id) to detailID, and the 2nd option (name) to detailName?

Comment: AFAIK, each option is supposed to have only one unique identifier as its value, so you can't directly bind one select to two different values. And of course, you can pass your `$details` array into your Vue instance something like [this](https://dev.to/aschmelyun/four-ways-to-pass-data-from-laravel-to-vue-5d8m). And then you can access your data more elegantly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code example just using vue.js

**Template**

```
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selectedDetailId">
    <option v-for="detail in details" v-bind:value="detail.id">
      {{ detail.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedDetailId: null,
    details: [
      { id: 1, name: 'A' },
      { id: 2, name: 'B' },
      { id: 3, name: 'C' }
    ]
  },
  methods:{
    post(){
       //your selected Id is this.selectedDetailId
    }
  }
})
```

You can find more details and examples in the official Vue.js docs.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Value-Bindings

Comment: I tried this with detail.name for the name of the option but it just shows on the frontend ```detailname```

Comment: Yes, use {{detail.name}} instead {{option.name}}, sorry. Did you initialize the Vue? You need to wrap the template with a div and set an id for this, then add the el property in the vue instance. I just edited the answer with this additional information.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set a v-model to your `select` element and bind the entire object to each `option` element instead of just the id like you are doing in your example.
Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/davidalejandro/pen/MWWLrzE) with a simple example.